# How do I successfully swap WETH for USDC using a smart contract and uniswap?

Tags: solidity, web3js, uniswap, decentralized-exchange

I deployed [my contract](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x1753317914B12cA1349509BD0Ab7f129c0e5074B#code) on the Ropsten Testnet, and on uniswap(the website) i swapped some eth for DAI, USDC, WETH.
Now i want to do the same with my contract.

The methods require TokenIn and TokenOut parameter, I didn't find the USDC address so i took what i believe to be the Token addresses of [DAI](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0xad6d458402f60fd3bd25163575031acdce07538d#writeContract) and [WETH](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xc778417e063141139fce010982780140aa0cd5ab#writeContract) on Ropsten.
But when i want to call getAmountOutMin i get the following error:

> call to tokenSwap.getAmountOutMin errored: execution reverted

What am i doing wrong? Are the Token addresses incorrect?
Is the UniSwap v2 Address incorrect? (0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D)

I also tried to swap tokens same problem doesn't work. ( i approved the contract before )